# Removing irrelevalent data with power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a situation where I have data in such format.

[image: See table]

There are thousands of rows with such status. What I would like to have is a new table where rows 2 and 3rd are removed and only the bottom row is left for reporting.

Currently, I have a VBA macro code, in which it first concatenates [sales document and product], checks and tags for repeating value. For the tagged lines, concatenated value times billed price is matched with next (-1 * Concatenate next value * billed price) and both lines are deleted in a loop.

This operation takes a long time sometimes as the size of the file can be big. I would like to move to power query because I have other related files, transformation happening there.

Would be glad if anyone can help me.
BR,
Manoj

Comment: You can make a reference to previous and previous -1 rows and then make a filter. Here is described how could you do it: https://www.thebiccountant.com/2018/07/12/fast-and-easy-way-to-reference-previous-or-next-rows-in-power-query-or-power-bi/

Comment: Hi Ricardo,
Thanks for the response, being pretty new to powerquery and m, i was not fully able to understand and apply the steps from link. Alexis had a better solution, which though partly, worked on me.
Have a good day, Manoj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend doing a Group By on the first four columns and using Sum as your aggregation for the billing column. Then simply filter out the 0 rows.

Comment: I can't address cases you don't show in your question. Please either edit your question or accept this answer ask a new question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for hint, it partly works. What i forget to mention earlier was that i there could be also a case a case like Below.
--> 1st a billing document (A) is created
--> 2nd another billing document (B) credit memo for same product.
--> 3rd another billing document (C) is created again with the same but +ve value. i want that third line to be in my leftover data. Just like A5 + B(-5) + C5 = C5, Had it not been other variable entry for same condition, the above solution (filter out 0) would work, but there are, and grouping & later expanding after filtering seems give an issue.